# validate multiple form fields by using custom validation

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a login form. I want to validate fields with `notempty()` rule. I want to display all error messages at once (where fields a are empty). In my case this does not happns.

my code is:

```
if(empty($this->data['Employee']['username'])){
    $this->Employee->invalidate('username','Please Enter User Name');
}
else if(empty($this->data['Employee']['password'])){
    $this->Employee->invalidate('password','Please Enter Password');
}
else if(empty($this->data['Employee']['project_id'])){
    $this->Employee->invalidate('project_id','Please Select Any Project.');
    $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'employees','action' => 'login'));
}
```

Login.ctp File:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Employee', array('action' => 'login'));?> 
<h2>Login</h2> <div id="login-area"> 
<?php echo $this->Form->input('username',array('div'=>false,'id'=>'loginusername'));?> 
<?php echo $this->Form->input('password',array('div'=>false,'type'=>'password','id'=>'passw‌​ord'));?> 
<?php echo $this->Form->input('project_id',array('id'=>'projects','empty'=>'Select'));?> 
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('submit',true));?>
```

Controller function :

```
function login(){
        $this->layout = 'login'; //pr($this->data);exit;

        if(isset($this->data['Employee'])){
            if(empty($this->data['Employee']['username'])){
                $this->Employee->invalidate('username','Please Enter User Name');
            }
            else if(empty($this->data['Employee']['password'])){
                $this->Employee->invalidate('password','Please Enter Password');
            }

            else{
                //$project_id = $this->data['Employee']['project_id'];
                $result=$this->Employee->findByUsername($this->data['Employee']['username']);
                $pwd=$result['Employee']['password'];echo $pwd; 
                $emp_id =$result['Employee']['id'];
                if($pwd==md5($this->data['Employee']['password'])){
                    //$this->Session->write('project_id',$project_id);
                    $this->Session->write('emp_id',$emp_id);
                    $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
                }

                else{
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Please enter valid username And password to login', true));
                }
            }
        }
```

How can I display all error msg together while submitting the form?

Comment: Can you also post the Controller action method for login

Comment: Can you also temporarily remove `<div id="login-area"> ` as currently this is giving you invalid markup. The `form->create` method creates a `<form>` tag and the `form->end` method creates the `</form>` so that open div tag needs to be removed or closed before the `form->end` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you are validating in controller that should look like this.

```
if(empty($this->data['Employee']['username'])){
    $this->Employee->invalidate('username','Please Enter User Name');
}
if(empty($this->data['Employee']['password'])){
    $this->Employee->invalidate('password','Please Enter Password');
}

if($this->Employee->validates()) {
    // do your login stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put validation in your Model class, CakePHP can handle all this out of the box.

Use the CakePHP formhelpers to render input boxes in your view and error messages will automatically be rendered when an invalid form is submit.

See details on model validation here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html

E.g. In your model class

```
public $validate = array(
    'username' => array(
        'rule'    => 'notEmpty',
        'message' => 'Please enter username'
    )
);
```

In your view (inside a form started with `$this->Form->create()`)

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('username'); ?>
```

Comment: This is not working in my case while am using model validations. i have two function in employees controller add() and login() functions.while m using model validations, its only applied on employee's add() function not on login()..so to sort this m using custom validations in my login function.

Comment: If its not working it is most likely because of a mistake in your view. You should focus on getting this working properly rather then hack your own validation together. If you show what you are trying in the login view I may be able to help get it working.

Comment: <?php  echo $this->Form->create('Employee', array('action' => 'login'));?>
   <h2>Login</h2>
    <div id="login-area">
 
       <?php echo $this->Form->input('username',array('div'=>false,'id'=>'loginusername'));?>

       <?php echo $this->Form->input('password',array('div'=>false,'type'=>'password','id'=>'password'));?>
       <?php echo $this->Form->input('project_id',array('id'=>'projects','empty'=>'Select'));?>
      
       <?php  echo $this->Form->end(__('submit',true));?>

Comment: Can you add this to your question and format it properly so I can read it? :)